# how to display a view on laravel 8 and not have a 404 NOT FOUND page?

Tags: php, laravel

I try to display a view but I get a 404 not found error, but my code seems correct

this is the route created

```
Route::get('talk',[\App\Http\Controllers\TalkController::class,'index'])->name('talk.index');
```

the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
class TalkController extends Controller
{
    public function index(): view
{
   return view('talk');
}
}
```

here is what I got as a result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF4Nb.png)

need help please

Comment: what URL are you trying to reach ?

Comment: href="{{route('talk.index')}}"

Comment: What is your link in the browser (URL)?

Comment: @PejmanKheyri  here is the link in the browser http://phoenixgroup.test/talk

Comment: Did you define the routing in web.php or api.php?
And where is your view file? Is it in resources/views/talk.blade.php

Comment: @PejmanKheyri  I defined the routing in web.php and the blade file is in resources/views/talk.blade.php

Comment: ADD dd("Hello"); BEFORE return view('talk'); in your index method and check do you see Hello in browser?

Comment: @PejmanKheyri I still have 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: Is there a prefix in your web.php routing? You cant reach the controller file! Check you are serving the right project or not.

Comment: I don't have a prefix, I checked the code from top to bottom and I don't see the error myself. I wonder if it's the new laravel 8.6 version that has the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was Facing the Same Problem   laravel Store cache and if  you stop the serv and start it all over you will still see the 404 so its better to do :-

```
php artisan optimize
```

php artisan optimize creates a compiled file of commonly used classes in order to reduce the amount of files that must be loaded on each request. The file is saved to, or overwrites, bootstrap/cache/compiled. php , which needs to be writable by the web server (PHP process).